# Closing app not from MainActivity does not work properly

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app with a SplashscreenActivity launching the app. So the SplashscreenActivity is the MainActivity and starts the HomeActivity. When I click back in the HomeActivity, I want to open a dialog asking if you want to exit the app. If you press yes, the app should be closed. I realised this with the following code:

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }, 1500)
    }
}
```

In the HomeActivity:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val dialog = BackPressedFragment()
    dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "BackPressedDialog")
}

override fun leave() {
    moveTaskToBack(true)
    finish()
}
```

The Dialog:

```
class BackPressedFragment: DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var listener: ILeave

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.leave))
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) {_,_->

            }
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) {_,_->
                listener.leave()
            }
        return builder.create()
    }

    interface ILeave {
        fun leave()
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        try {
            listener = context as ILeave
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but there is one problem. When I reenter the app, the MainActivity does not launch the HomeActivity. Being stuck in the MainActivity, I have to leave and renter again, then the HomeActivity gets launched.

Comment: `moveTaskToBack(true)` what do you need this for?

Comment: I found this here on stackoverflow. Without this line only the activity closes, not the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly `MainActivity` was never destroyed when exiting the app from `HomeActivity`. If this is the case then when you revisit a previously created `MainActivity` its `onCreate()`, which launches `HomeActivity`, is not called.

This can be solved by either setting `android:noHistory="true"` on `MainActivity` in the AndroidManifest.xml. Or, by calling `finish()` after launching `HomeActivity`:

```
    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
```